# Arch Linux UEFI bootable usb installation media

Tags: linux, boot, usb, arch-linux, uefi

I want to install Arch Linux in UEFI mode, but I fail at booting the installation media in UEFI mode. What I have done so far is:

- Create msdos partition table on usb key OR create gpt partition table on usb key
- write the official iso to the usb key with `dd bs=4M if=archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdX`
- reboot the system

When I try to select the dialog only shows me a BIOS/CSM entry to boot, which works perfectly. But there is option to boot in UEFI mode.

Aditionaly, when I try to view the partitions in gparted i get the message `dev/sdd contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?` and when I click `yes` I get the message `The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.`
Also there is only partition that is unallocted and has a warning sign, when I view the details I see the errors listed above. 
What have I done wrong? Have I forgotten something?

Comment: Please provide more (hardware) details on the machine you’re using.

Comment: OK, sorry, first I have to say that I often managed it to boot from uefi, and i also managed it once to boot with the same ISO in uefi mode, the motherboard is a fatality h87, are there more specs you need to know?

Comment: I tried around a bit more and found a solution, which is to use rufus on Windows with gpt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about boot disks, but perhaps you did something wrong while creating the boot disk. If you have a computer running Windows, OSX, or Linux, you can use a boot disc creator. If you have a windows computer, I would recommend [YUMI by pen drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). It is a very esy to use tool, and is even multi-bootable. This means you can have more than one OS on 1 pen drive.